# Changing the bounds of a TreeNode - hit tests for custom treenodes

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode

I have created an overriden Treeview that displays nodes with multiple icons - the default icon plus others (which I call secondary icons). Because of the presence the secondary icons, that are specified in an overriden TreeNode class, the text label is moved over as appropriate. The tree is operating in **tvEvents.DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawAll** to handle this, with appropriate code in the DrawNode event.

My question is, how do I override the inbuilt treeview behaviour for hit detection - currently, the hitdetection works when clicking secondary icons and some of the text, obviosly - due to the presence of 0 or more secondary icons the label will be moved over my multiples of 16 (the icon size). Obviously, there is the TreeNode property **bounds** that defines the dimensions of a "standard" node, which I think will then be used in treeview hittests, but I'm uncertain as what to do next.

A little help will be appreciated.

Comment: You feed HitTest with x and y values. Can't you reduce the x-values if they are too large?

Comment: Can you expand on that, please?

Comment: Well, do you actually use HitTest in the 1st place? You show no code.. Also a screenshot might help. If the 1st Hittest hits the empty space you could do a 2nd hittest with (e.X - icon.Width, e.Y)..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545931/custom-treenode-bounds?rq=1